# jQuery animate before displaying home page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am newbie to jquery. My client needs a homepage in which first the logo will appear with some animation and pause for couple of seconds, then the title of the company, then the logo and the title below the logo will appear with some animation. How should I proceed? Is
`$("#mydiv").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();` is the right way to do this? I am not able to find a way how to achieve this.
UPDATE:
I tried the following:

```
<body>
<script>
$("#myElem").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();
</script>
<div id="myElem">
DEMO DIV LINES</div>
</body>
```

But it is not animating at all, just showing  `DEMO DIV LINES`!!

Comment: We are happy to help you fix problems with your existing code, but this site is not designed to be a place to request complete solutions from scratch. You may get better results by finding a similar effect online, writing code to duplicate that effect, and asking here if you get stuck while writing that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use the oncomplete functions:

```
// even though opacity is allready 1 (100% visible) 
//it will take 5000ms to trigger the onComplete function(){}
$("#startpage").animate({opacity:1},5000, function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function(){
        // make code here that will show other page:
       $('#realpage').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Made an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UtMYr/1/)

Comment: What is an `oncomplete` function?  Did you mean to say `callback` function?

Comment: Well, I think the name says it all :P a function that gets executed on completion :P Can be an existing function or an anonymous function (like I've used in my example).
If you would have an function called exampleFunction() you would do `$(elem).fadeIn(milisec, exampleFunction);` *Not sure if I should input it as a string ( `'exampleFunction'`). Anonymous functions are used way more often :)

Comment: That's more commonly called a `callback` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider hiding the div first.

```
<div id="myElem" style="display:none">
```

Ideally, you would ofcourse create a css class called `hidden`, and then assign that class.